# Android NDK - OpenGL ES 2.0 - library linking

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

Writing OpenGL ES 2.0 program using NDK. I am facing error `Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API`.

My program does not have any OpenGL ES 1.x calls. The emulator GPU support is also enabled. The makefile is as follows

```
/*Android.mk*/

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := NDKTestApp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := firstTriangle.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

I am not linking version 1.x library anywhere but in log still I can see

```
loaded .../libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
loaded .../libGLESv2_emulation.so
```

So I think the problem is functions are being searched in version 1 library, which it won't find there quite obviously and so are the errors.

So How can I stop linking against version 1 library, like forcibly avoid loading it?

Context is created using

```
const EGLint context_attribs[] = {
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE
};
.
.
.
context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, context_attribs);
```

Comment: What call is failing?  Looks like you're using the emulator; have you tried it on a real device?  Do you have GPU acceleration enabled in the emulator?

Comment: `glCreateShader(), glShaderSource(), glGetShaderiv()` and all similar 2.0 calls are failing. Have tried on real device also, it gives black screen. Yes, GPU acceleration is enables in emulator and my GPU is Radeon 6770M, which supports OpenGL 4.1, so it supports shaders, so it must be supporting ES2.0.

Comment: by the way, where are these libraries located(.so files), because you see, the problem is version 1 library is getting loaded, so calls are traced there(late binding is pointing there) so if i somehow force that version 1 library to not to get loaded, problem will get solved.. (scariest thing in the world is to delete version 1 .so, so where is it on PC, unable to find it..)

Comment: It's okay for both libraries to be loaded.  The calls get routed based on how your EGL context is configured.  Can you show how you're configuring EGL?

Comment: In particular, the `EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION` should be set to 2 in your call to `eglCreateContext`.

Comment: question is edited to add context creation

Comment: In your code, at the point where the GLES2 calls are failing, call `glGetString` with `GL_VENDOR`, `GL_RENDERER`, and `GL_VERSION`, log the result, and paste the output here.  That'll tell us what you've got configured.  You should see GLES 2 and some host GPU info.